# Apache Spark operation on .join dataset

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, k-means

I am working on pyspark on the clustering mllib. In python we have only two API's one is predict which gives the cluster value for the point and one is cluster.centers which gives the cluster centers.

I was been asked to find the most densely populated cluster using the formula (number of points in cluster)/(radius of the cluster)^2

I have figured out a way to find both the values (number of points in cluster, 
radius of the cluster). Now I have two datasets in (K,V) format in which one of the dataset carries (clusterValue,Radius of the cluster) and other dataset has (ClusterValue,Number of points in the Cluster).

I am stuck here how to compute the value of the density using the two datasets. Is there is a way we can compute the values using the datasets?

I used .join RDD Transformation by which i was able to get the combined dataset (k,(v,w)) i.e (clustervalue,(radius,number)) .But not able to figure out how to apply any function on this type of dataset. Please help me out if anyone of you have faced this issue before

I am using spark 1.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply any function to you joined RDD using the `.map` transformation, for instance to divide number by radius:

```
kvw=[("X",(2.0,1.0)),("Y",(3.0,2.0))]
kvwRDD = sc.parallelize(kvw)
kvwRDD.map(lambda (k,(v,w)): (k, w/v))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#basics.

```
densities = joined.map(
    lambda (cluster, (radius, number)): (cluster, number / radius / radius))
```

Comment: Today when I ran the code with the input in spark environment I saw a strange behavior. For each and every run I get different output. This may be because of the parallelism I guess when the file is been read from HDFS the input points are been divided and the clustering is applied on the each part of the file. If in this case the system behavior will not give the correct outputs i guess. Please correct me if i am thinking wrong.

Comment: `join` and `map` are completely deterministic. File reading is also deterministic. It's probably what you do between them that causes non-deterministic behavior. You could open another question if it's a problem.